# The mobile site is showing in bold words that should be shown in italics

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

I was looking at, with my iPod, [an answer I gave](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/getting-our-dirty-words-into-one-place/1540#1540) for the meta site of *English Language & Usage*, and I noticed that words that are supposed to be in italics are shown in bold.

This is the source and the preview of the answer, as shown from a Mac.

[image: Mac screenshot]

The answer shows the words in italics, when seen from Safari 5.0.5 on my Mac (as any other browser running on a computer does).

This is the same answer shown from the iPod.

[image: iPod screenshot]

Comment: It seems ok for me, iOS 4.3.3, 3GS

Comment: I now see it as I should too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in our last deploy.

Comment: I should remember to post also the SE revision reported when I notice the issue. `:-)`