# On the mobile theme, words that should be in italic are shown in bold, and italic

Tags: bug, status-completed, posts, mobile-web

For example, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/gain-flag-weight-after-passing-3k-rep/110850#110850) contains `_not an answer_, or selecting _other_` but "not an answer" and "other" are rendered in italic and bold.

[image: screenshot]

The same happens in other SE sites, as it is evident [in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/is-it-correct-to-say-i-would-do-something-be-it-me/47262#47262).

[image: screenshot]

If it makes any difference, I am noticing this on my iPod running iOS 5.

This issue is similar to [The mobile site is showing in bold words that should be shown in italics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98451/the-mobile-site-is-showing-in-bold-words-that-should-be-shown-in-italics) I reported in the past; the difference is that previously, words that should be in italic were shown in bold, while now they are shown in bold **and** italic. The other report has been marked as fixed, and it was really fixed, except that now the mobile theme doesn't (again) correctly render those words that should be just in italic.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't your device? I mean, did you check the source to see if that really gets applied?

Comment: No, it's really like that @asylum

Comment: It also happens in iOS 4.2.1, but only while in the mobile view.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I am reporting the bug for the mobile theme; I was used to tag such questions with [tag:mobile-theme], but it seems the tag is not used anymore, or it has been renamed, and I don't find it anymore.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, I understand that. I was just confirming that it was the theme causing it and not the device doing it automatically.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Oh, yes. If it were the device, then I would see the same issue when I am not using the mobile theme.

Comment: I assumed this was intended, perhaps wrongly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The mobile site is showing in bold words that should be shown in italics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98451/the-mobile-site-is-showing-in-bold-words-that-should-be-shown-in-italics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next build.